# Mod rewrite - File attribute "-f" test fails even when the regular file exists

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

According to the [mod rewrite doc regarding -f](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> Treats the TestString as a pathname and tests whether or not it
>   exists, and is a regular file.

And so, I have the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond /efs/my-project/angular-json/$1/$2.json -f
RewriteRule ^/(test-folder)/(california)$ http://noderender:8080/$1/$2?mode=client [P,QSA,E=CACHE_CHECK:]
```

And the stat of the file

```
$ stat /efs/my-project/angular-json/test-folder/california.json
  File: /efs/my-project/angular-json/test-folder/california.json
  Size: 1689        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 5373962     Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/    choz)   Gid: ( 33/    www-data)
Access: 2019-07-25 00:00:20.811760100 +0800
Modify: 2019-07-23 21:43:48.177173780 +0800
Change: 2019-07-23 21:43:48.177173780 +0800
 Birth: -
```

And, here's the log for it,

```
applying pattern '^/(test-folder)/(california)$' to uri '/test-folder/california'
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/my-project/test-folder/california' pattern='!-f' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/my-project/test-folder/california' pattern='!-d' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/efs/my-project/angular-json/test-folder/california.json' pattern='-f' => not-matched
```

The question is, why the **-f** is not matched there? Is there any httpd configuration that I am missing and causing this?

Answer (score 0):

To help other people whose facing the same problem. In my case, `/efs` is a mounted path from another disk. Unmounting it and serve `/efs` from the same disk as apache solves this issue.

So, in my **/etc/fstab**

```
# Commented this line
# /dev/disk/by-uuid/741805d1-d67a-4936-8b93-c3d223351615 /efs auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I didn't dig this any further, but my conclusuion is that apache (www-data) is unable to read the files from another disk? Weird.